# Is Dive Into Python outdated?

Tags: python

I am learning Python, and I saw Dive Into Python and it looks cool and all, but it was released in 2004.  So, what I am wondering is if Python 2.x has changed enough since 2004 that Dive Into Python has become so obsolete.  And are there any more recent online textbooks like that for Python that can get me to become an awesome programmer?

Answer (score 23):

Well, there **is** [*Dive Into Python 3*](http://diveintopython3.net/)...

> *Dive Into Python 3* covers Python 3 and its differences from Python 2. Compared to [*Dive Into Python*](http://diveintopython.net/), it’s about 20% revised and 80% new material.

Comment: I thought I heard 2 was still where it's at.  So, which path of the Python ninja is better to take?  2 or 3?

Comment: It depends - [Python 2, or Python 3](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)?

Comment: Idk.  I heard more people are still using 2, but has 3 become widely used yet?

Comment: Are you kidding me? http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3#So_which_version_should_I_use.3F

Comment: Latest Linux (like Centos 7) and Mac (like OS 10.9) versions still come with python 2.x as default. I am surprised to see this for many years now.

Comment: @MattBall be less surprised when the wiki's [Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) sends you to that page, then says "From now on we'll assume you're using Python 2"

Comment: @RobertGrant I think you meant to address Andreas in that comment.

Comment: @MattBall actually no, although I see he was also surprised :) I meant that in response to your "Are you kidding me?" :)

Comment: @RobertGrant oh, I see. I was annoyed because the OP appeared to be completely unable to use a basic Google search.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [new version of Dive into Python](http://diveintopython3.net/) that focuses on 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not obsolete. It is still a good resource which can teach you effective python programming.

You might also like to read [Dive Into Python 3](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/) by the same author, as he adapts the book for the python3 language.

Answer (score 1):

Switch over to *[Dive into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.net/)*

Also see, [What's new in `Dive into Python 3` ?](http://diveintopython3.net/whats-new.html)